# Why Jolokia is not working with Elassandra?

Tags: jmx, jolokia, elassandra

I am using elassandra-6.2.3.4 and jolokia-jvm-1.6.0-agent.jar.

But when I start cassandra with ES using below command : -

```
./cassandra -e
```

Then it is showing some error related to json-simple  and jolokia jar.
So how can I configure jolokia to access cassandra JMX metrics along with elassandra?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without the error log, it hard to say.

If it's related to "JarHell", it is because the elassandra JVM refuses to start when a duplicated class is found in the classpath.

Probably jolokia-1.6.0 and elasandra-6.2.3.4 have a common dependency "json-simple". You may try to remove this class from the jolokia jar...

Repeat the process until all conflicts are solved.